# How can I name each graph

Tags: python, plot, sympy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2DNE.png)I want to name each graph 't = -4','t = 2',,,,'t = 4' with sympy.
What sentences should I add to do this. The function u(x,t) has been already defined.

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.plotting import plot as symplot
symplot(u(x,-4),u(x,-2),u(x,0),u(x,2),u(x,4))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using a specific label for each function plot called with  `legend=True` like the following:

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.plotting import plot
x = symbols('x')
p1 = plot(x**2, label="first function",show=False, legend=True)
p2 = plot(x, -x, label="second function",show=False, legend=True)
p1.extend(p2)  # any other shape can be added to the original using this method. 

p1.show()
```

It should come out like this ([example](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html)):
[image]

If you have p3 then you can plot it like with p1 and p2 then just write p1.extend(p3) etc...

Comment: I copied and pasted your code on my jupyter notebook, but my labels still show 'x**2' , 'x' , '-x' not 'first function'.

Comment: I cannot give you feedback if I do not see your code. Share your jupyter notebook code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The principle is to create a figure with plots, without showing it. Each plot can be adjusted individually using its index, and the updated figure can be plotted when ready.

```
from sympy import init_printing, plot
from sympy.abc import x
init_printing()

# Functions
y1 = 1 / (2*x) + 3
y2 = 2 * x**2 + 2

# Argument dicts
lims = {'xlim':[-2,2], 'ylim':[0,6]}
args = {'legend':True, 'show':False}

# Create plots, but don't show the figure
plots = plot(y1, y2, **lims, **args)

# Adjust plots individually for any parameter, then show the adjusted figure
labels = ('f', 'g')
for i, p in enumerate(plots): p.label = labels[i]
plots.show()
```

[image]